# Movie/Show about a serial killer

Tags: story-identification

So a while ago, probably in the 2008-2012 timeframe, I watched a movie/show that essentially traumatized me for a few years. I don't remember anything about the movie except this one very specific scene.

A tall, sturdy African-American man is trying to get into a locked down building, possibly an office or Federal building. Upstairs, in a well-lit, database type room (imagine CSI-Cyber), there are quite a few people working, and one worker has his daughter with him for what I think is 'bring your child to work day'. They're all terrified because their building is under lockdown. The doors are securely locked (but with retinal scanners), and to enter, the African-American man takes a security guard hostage and brings him to an operating room, where he and another person(s) (gruesomely) remove the guard's eyeball with a scalpel and impales it upon a skewer. Leaving the OR, the African-American man twirls the skewer in his hand, scans the eyeball to the retinal scanner, and enters the building.

Unfortunately, I don't think I remember much else, I was too horrified to continue watching.

This was a high quality, colorized movie/show, quite well done.

Figured I'd give this a try!

Any ideas are appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Possibly Demolition Man (1993), in it Wesley Snipes gouges out a mans eye to Escape Prison.

He ends up twirling the Eyeball on a pen.

But This is a Prison escape, and there is no daddy Daughter scene.

[Youtube of Demolision Man eyeball scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hgqw1kiuz4Q)

Comment: Thank you! Yep, that's it. Not sure where the Daddy daughter scene came from, and I hadn't remembered his hair that color, but indeed, the scene was the same. Much appreciation.